# How to execute SQL Queries via Powershell without using an external SQL file?

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell, scripting, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm a DBA, and I'm trying to execute queries via the PS instead of logging into each server using SQL Developer. But so far I've only had success with using an external SQL file. I'm trying to do it with a variable stated within the PS Script.

Script:

```
$sqlQuery='GRANT ROLE TO USER;quit;'
$cmd = "cmd.exe"
$srvList = 'SRVONE','SRVTWO','SRVTHREE','SRVFOUR'
echo $srvList
$init = "/c sqlplus user/password//DB_"
$mid = ":1521/"
foreach ($srv in $srvList){
$srvEx +=$init
$srvEx +=$srv
$srvEx +=$mid
$srvEx +=$srv
$srvEx +=" @"
$srvEx +=$sqlQuery
Write-Host $srvEx
&cmd $srvEx;
$srvEx=''
}
```

Above is the script I've made. It's able to connect to the SQL database, however the query in the variable $sqlQuery won't run and give any results.

Comment: If you manually copy paste `$srvEx` into a command window and run it, what happens? It sounds like maybe `sqlplus` is prompting for something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use [dba tools](https://dbatools.io/).  It is quite simple to do with the Invoke-DbaQuery cmdlet.

I have a local server called vm4win10.  However, this will work for any version of SQL server in which you can make a connection.  Below are variables I am going to use.

```
# Set variables
$svr = "vm4win10"
$usr = "jminer"
$dbs = "dbs4advwrks"
$path = "c:\transfer"
```

Grab the password for the standard user "jminer".  This could be a windows user if needed.

```
# Credential (standard security)
$crd = (Get-Credential "$usr")
```

In my example, I am going to dump the adventure works customer table to a csv file.  But this query can easily be a server task.

```
# extract data
$cust = Invoke-DbaQuery $svr $SqlCredential $crd -Database $dbs -Query 'SELECT * FROM dbs4advwrks.dbo.DimCustomer'

# rec count
$cust.Count

# first record
$cust[0]
```

Showing the first element of the array of Data Row objects.

[image]

The next snippet pipes the $cust variable to a cmdlet to write a csv file.

```
# write file
$cust | Export-Csv -Path "$path\dim-customer.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

This shows the first few lines in my favorite editor, notepad++.

[image]

So, yes I got a little off track.  But dba tools has a boat load of cmdlets for the accidental DBA.

Back to your use case.  Let us make believe the adventure works database is installed on three servers.  The user Robin has been added to each server.  Now we want to grant control rights to the database.  The credential for jminer has sysadmin access to each server.

```
# tsql to execute
$sql = "GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::AdventureWorks TO Robin;"

# first server
$svr = "test1svr"
$dbs= "AdventureWorks"
$ret = Invoke-DbaQuery $svr -SqlCredential $crd -Database $dbs -Query $sql

# second server
$svr = "test2svr"
$dbs= "AdventureWorks"
$ret = Invoke-DbaQuery $svr -SqlCredential $crd -Database $dbs -Query $sql

# third server
$svr = "test3svr"
$dbs= "AdventureWorks"
$ret = Invoke-DbaQuery $svr -SqlCredential $crd -Database $dbs -Query $sql
```

In short, life is easy with dbatools.

Comment: OP is using Oracle

Comment: AH .. different story. Now I see the phrase "SQL Developer".  I will post something that will work with Oracle.  Might not be as clean.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article.  It uses ODBC but should work fine.  This will require the client tools for ORACLE to be installed on the Jump Server that has access to the Oracle Servers.  You might even have to set up your tnsnames.ora file.

https://www.andersrodland.com/working-with-odbc-connections-in-powershell/

Step 1 can be done by hand if you want.  Step 2 gets the DSN connection.  Step 3 executes the SQL.  It might prompt you for credentials if you can not store them.  This is not as pretty as DBA tools!

```
# 1 - Create a DSN (change for oracle)
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "MyPayroll" -DriverName "SQL Server Native Client 10.0" -DsnType "System" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=MyServer", "Trusted_Connection=Yes", "Database=Payroll")

# 2 - Get the DSN
$dsn = Get-OdbcDsn -Name "MyPayroll" -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit"

# 3 - Execute non query
$sql = "GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::AdventureWorks TO Robin;"
Set-ODBC-Data $sql, $dsn
```

You will have to setup a DSN connection for each server you want to work with.

Comment: Looks great but the OP is not using trusted connection. Is there a code sample that uses login/password?

Answer (score 0):

For DBAs it's been classic for over two decades to have Oracle client installed and use sqlplus to run SQL and PL/SQL scripts.
SQLDeveloper is used so that you may have a "nice" graphical interface to see the results of queries and to edit stored program units and see compilation errors easier than when using the plain sqlplus. Yet for running scripts often times sqlplus is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Output

```
C:\upwork\sql_run_all_servers>powershell .\run_sql_all_servers.ps1 
SET session NLS_LANG: AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8                             
=======================================================
Script start time : 2023-02-28 17:50:06
Script is run on the server : DEV 
-------------------------------------------------------
Script is run on the server : DEV19 
-------------------------------------------------------
Script is run on the server : DEMO19
-------------------------------------------------------
Script stop time : 2023-02-28 17:50:12
```

Script

```
$username = "scott"
$password = "tiger"
$connect_string_list = "DEV","DEV19","DEMO19"
$log_file = "C:\upwork\sql_run_all_servers\log_file.log"

# NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS
$NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=".,"
$NLS_DATE_FORMAT="DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS"
# Log file 
$full_log_path=$log_file
#Set NLS_LANG for session sqlplus 
#"AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8"
$NLS_LANG="AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8"

$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'Out-File:Encoding' = 'utf8'}

#Set NLS_LANG for session sqlplus 
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("NLS_LANG",$NLS_LANG , [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::PROCESS)
$env_path_NLS=[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("NLS_LANG", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::PROCESS)

echo "SET session NLS_LANG: $env_path_NLS" | tee-object -Append  -filepath $full_log_path  

$sqlQuery_show_user_tables = 
@"
set heading off
set termout OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TAB OFF
set pause off
set verify off
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set trimspool on
set timing off
set echo off
set linesize 10000
set pagesize 0
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='$NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='$NLS_DATE_FORMAT'; 
select  TNAME  from tab where tabtype='TABLE' and tname not like 'BIN$%'
;
exit
"@
                         
echo "===========================================================================================" | tee-object -Append  -filepath $full_log_path 

$date_time_start = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"            
$date_time_log = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMddHHmmss"            

Write-host "Script start time : $date_time_start "
try
{
echo "Script start time :  $date_time_start ">>$full_log_path
}
catch {
Write-Host "Log File $full_log_path.  Other type of error was found:"
Write-Host "Exception type is $($_.Exception.GetType().Name)"
exit
}

foreach ($server_alias in $connect_string_list)
{
echo  "Script is run on the server : $server_alias "  | tee-object -Append  -filepath $full_log_path  

$sqlOutput_tab = $sqlQuery_show_user_tables | sqlplus -s $username/$password@$server_alias

Out-File -filepath $full_log_path -append -inputobject $sqlOutput_tab  -Encoding utf8

echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"  | tee-object -Append  -filepath $full_log_path  
}
$date_time_stop = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"            
echo "Script stop time : $date_time_stop" | tee-object -Append  -filepath $full_log_path
```